# What is the best way to build a complex NSCompoundPredicate?

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, nspredicate

I need to build an `NSPredicate` with many pieces of data.  For example in SQL I would do something like the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TRANSACTIONS
  WHERE CATEGORY IN (categoryList)
    AND LOCATION IN (locationList)
    AND TYPE IN (typeList)
    AND NOTE contains[cd] "some text"
    AND DATE >= fromDate
    AND DATE <+ toDate
```

I'm struggling with how to build this as an `NSPredicate` for use with Core Data.  I've read the documentation... which only provides simplistic examples.  If anybody can point me to a more complex example I would certainly appreciate it.

---

Well, I had an answer out here for two years that many people found helpful.  My post was deleted.  Here is the updated URL with the solution.

https://www.radeeccles.com/convert-sql-statement-to-an-nspredicate-for-use-with-core-data/

Comment: Did you try inputting your where clause in the predicate. It has a method to build one from string that is pretty powerful.

Comment: Im not aware of any place that lets me specify a SQL statement which generates a predicate.  Please advise.

Comment: I don't know why my post keeps getting deleted. This article has helped MANY people http://www.radeeccles.com/convert-sql-statement-to-an-nspredicate-for-use-with-core-data/

Answer (score 9):

What you need to do is to create a Predicate for each one of your clauses. For example let's break down your query:

1. SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS
2. WHERE CATEGORY IN (categoryList)
3. AND LOCATION IN (locationList)
4. AND TYPE IN (typeList)
5. AND NOTE contains[cd] "some text"
6. AND DATE >= fromDate AND DATE <+ toDate

Based on this, you have 5 predicates (2-6). So let's work on them one by one.

```
 NSPredicate *inCategoryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Category IN %@", categoryList];

 NSPredicate *locationPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location IN %@", locationList];

 NSPredicate *typePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Type IN %@", typeList];

 NSPredicate *notePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Note contains[c] %@", @"Some Text"];

 NSPredicate *startDatePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Date => @", fromDate];

 NSPredicate *endDatePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Date <= @", toDate];
```

Now you just need to join them into just one predicate: [Apple's documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html):

> You should structure compound predicates to minimize the amount of
>   work done. Regular expression matching in particular is an expensive
>   operation. In a compound predicate, you should therefore perform
>   simple tests before a regular expression;

This being said then you should start with the "easy" predicates first. So:

```
NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: startDatePredicate, endDatePredicate, inCategoryPredicate, locationPredicate, typePredicate, notePredicate];
```

You can always get an idea of what the predicate (sql where) looks like if you NSLog it.

Comment: Is it possible to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388393/create-complicated-nscompoundpredicate-in-swift-3) please?