# how to create a predicate in which % work as a string in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, nsarray

I am using a Predicate for filtering a NSArray but, when a create Predicate like this

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@ && %K contains[c] %@ ",
                                                            kUnitUnitcategoryKey,
                                                            @"Blood Pressure Diastolic",
                                                            kUnitUnitNameKey,
                                                            [_txtOxygenSaturationUnit.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

after this "predicate" string is : "unit_category CONTAINS[c] "Blood Pressure Diastolic" AND unit_name CONTAINS[c] "%" "

```
NSArray *results = [_arrUnitsName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

it will return Zero records.

Now, how can i used % as a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely ugly way to write a somewhat complex predicate. You'll find using NSCompoundPredicates are MUCH easier to manage and modify. Simply create your multiple NSPredicates then use an andPredicate to combine all of your predicates.

[What is the best way to build a complex NSCompoundPredicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955717/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-a-complex-nscompoundpredicate)

As far as the actual question of how can you use % as a string? Test each predicate individually if you are getting zero results for easier debugging and you'll find the issue much easier.

Comment: It's probably easier just to use a predicate with a block for the second part and then compound them into a single AND predicate.