# Create complicated NSCompoundPredicate in swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

I want to create a complicated **NSCompoundPredicate** in swift 3, however, I don't know how to do this.

Suppose I have 5 predicates (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5). I want to implement below conditions:

```
compound1 = (p1 AND p2 AND p3) // NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, 
                              //subpredicates: predicates)
compound2 = (p4 AND p5) // NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, 
                       //subpredicates: predicates)
compound3 = (compound1 OR compound2) // problem is here

fetchRequest.predicate = compound3
```

***NSCompoundPredicate*** as it's second argument gets array of NSPredicates that it doesn't desire. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NSCompoundPredicate` inherits from `NSPredicate`, therefore you
can pass the compound predicates created in the first steps
as subpredicate to another compound predicate:

```
let compound1 = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [p1, p2, p3])
let compound2 = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [p4, p5])
let compound3 = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [compound1, compound2])

fetchRequest.predicate = compound3
```